# input, text area styling after changing text?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have one text area/input[type=text]. I want to style its background color to changed when someone click into text area.. this is happening with input:focus

till here its fine but i want this styling to remain if user changes or types in some text.. if user doesn't type anything its background color will be back to white... if typed some text background color will stay red... I'm having trouble with second part...
my sample html

```
 <input placeholder='What should  I call you?' type='text'>
```

css i'm trying..

```
     input:focus, input.active,
    select:focus,
    select.active,
    textarea:focus,
    textarea.active {
        background: red;
      }
input{
background:white;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like validation style (adds error class if input is invalid, otherwise adds valid class if it matches your criteria) have a look at [jQuery.validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**++** you have to consider when user typed text or removed text from  input, when user typed something background should get color but when user removed that text it should back to white, not only on `focus` or `blur`. you should use `jquery` because `css` can not understand is there any text in field or not.

```
$('#myInput').focus(function(){
$(this).css('backgroundColor','red');
});

$('#myInput').blur(function(){
if($(this).val().length > 0) {
$(this).css('backgroundColor','red');
} else {
$(this).css('backgroundColor','white');
}
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zc77Lyr9/)**

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using the onChange event?

[W3Schools onChange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

See this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3R0kzKjnN4i9akIEzMc7?p=preview) - is that what you're attempting to accomplish?

```js
// Code goes here

function changed(element){
  element.style.background = 'red';
};
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

input:focus, input.active,
    select:focus,
    select.active,
    textarea:focus,
    textarea.active {
        background: red;
      }
input{
background:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input placeholder='What should  I call you?' type='text' onChange=changed(this)>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey thank you... yours is also correct... but it doesn't recognize the deletion of text.... :)